# Calculating sum of columns C

Tags: arrays, c

I am new to programming in c, on a question I received the code below and was asked to add a code block that would calculate the sum of each column in the array(which is given by the user) and return the index of column that has the biggest sum in it.
My best attempt was to create 4 sums and add each column's numbers to its sum, but it seemed too messy and I couldn't make it work, added the code below.
Would love to see an example of how it can be done, ty.

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#define ROW 3   
#define COL 4
void input(int m[][COL]) ;
int sumAllMat(int m[][COL]) ;

int main(){
    int mat[ROW][COL],sum;
    input(mat);
    sum =sumAllMat(mat);
    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}
void input(int m[][COL]) {
    int r,c;
for (r=0 ; r<ROW ; r++){
    printf("\n Enter values into row #%d : \n", r);
    for (c=0 ; c<COL ; c++)
        scanf("%d", &m[r][c]);
}
}
int sumAllMat(int m[][COL]) {
    int r,c,s=0;
    for (c=0 ; c<COL ; c++) 
        for (r=0 ; r<ROW ; r++)
           s += m[r][c];
    return(s);
}
```

.............................

```
void test(int m[][COL]){
        int a,b,c,d,i,j;
        for(i=0;i<COL;i++){
            for(j=0;j<ROW;j++){
                if(i=0){
                    a+=m[i][j];
                }
                if(i=1){
                    b+=m[i][j];
                }
                if(i=2){
                    c+=m[i][j];
                }
                else{
                    d+=m[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        if(a>b>c>d){
            printf("The column with the biggest sum is column 0");
        }
        if(b>a>c>d){
            printf("The column with the biggest sum is column 1");;
        }
        if(c>a>b>d){
            printf("The column with the biggest sum is column 2");;
        }
        if(d>a>b>c){
            printf("The column with the biggest sum is column 3");;
        }
        else{
            printf("The sum of all columns is even");
        }
    }
```

Comment: C does not support chained comparisons like `a>b>c>d` (it is interpreted very differently from what one may expect). Use `a > b && b > c && c > d`

Comment: Very few programming languages support mathematical notation such as `a>b>c>d`. C does not. While the code will compile and even run, it won't generally do what you expect.

Comment: What if the number of columns isn't 4?

Comment: Calculate the sum of the first column, put this in a variable. Then loop through the remaining columns, calculating each sum. If the new sum is more than the variable, replace the variable with the new sum. At the end, you'll have the largest sum.

Comment: And use another variable to hold the column number with the largest sum.

Comment: Consider creating an array of sums, updating it while reading the matrix and then search the index of the maximum in it. Note that in the posted function the inner index should be the one representing the column, not the row.

Comment: What do you mean by that? , You can change the number of columns but I don't see how it changes anything about the code.

Comment: @Barmar Am i not looping through the array already to calculate the sum of each column in the code at the end of the question?.

Comment: You are, but you're not comparing the sums in a general way.

Comment: I can't think about a way  to check which one has the biggest sum efficiently while remembering  which column it was because I have to print the number of the column,
not the sum it self

Comment: start small. First, can you write a function that simply returns the sum of a column? Don't worry at all about "efficiency" right now. Get something working first.

Comment: Yes, I can, but for 1 column it seems like a waste of space.

Comment: What's a waste of space? An array is contiguous memory space, none is wasted. Your function prototype for summing a column should be something like `int sumColumn(int matrix[][COLS], int colIndex);` Make it loop through all the rows at the specified `colIndex`, summing each value, then return that sum.

Comment: here is a [working example](https://godbolt.org/z/3xz96E9b8) of how to sum each column. From here, think about how to identify the column with the largest sum, all the pieces are there. I also recommend you hardcode your array as I have just for debugging, it's a huge time saver not having to enter the matrix values each time you want to test. You can bring the manual entry back once you get everything else working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by creating three variables

- `prevSum`: the best sum so far
- `sum`: current sum
- `prevIndex` the best known sum's index

and then:

```
void test(int m[][COL]){
        int prevSum = -1;
        int prevIndex = -1;
        int sum = 0;
        for(i=0;i<COL;i++){
            sum = 0;
            for(j=0;j<ROW;j++){
                sum += m[j][i];
            }
            if ((prevIndex < 0) || (sum > prevSum)) {
                prevIndex = i;
                prevSum = sum;
            }
        }
        printf("The column with the biggest sum is column %d", prevIndex);
    }
```

Simple solution and much more dynamic than the one you have started working with.

Comment: @Maorb17 note that a very important point to make here is that this answer does not assume the number of elements to be computed to be four. So this will work with 5 columns or 6 columns, etc.